# Problems making an awk between range of columns

Tags: awk

I have a file called sds

```
$head sds
2557 386 fs://name/user/hive/ware/doc1/do_fact/date=20190313/fact=6
2593 393 fs://name/user/hive/ware/toc1/do_gas/idi_centr=6372/mes=20
2594 343 fs://name/user/hive/ware/dac2/do_gas2/idi_centr=6354/mes=21
349  307 fs://name/user/hive/ware/tec2/do_des/mes=25
340  332 fs://name/user/hive/ware/dc1/venta/year=2018/month=12
```

I want delete `/user/hive/ware` and replace `$7 ~ /_1$` for `1`and `other $7` for `2` using awk.

The code that I used was:

```
awk -F"/" '{ if ($7 ~ /_1$/)
print $1"//"$3"/1/"$7-$NF
else
print $1"//"$3"/2/"$7-$NF}' sds
```

but the result is bad.

I would like and output like:

```
2557 386 fs://name/1/do_fact/date=20190313/fact=6
2593 393 fs://name/1/do_gas/idi_centr=6372/mes=20
2594 343 fs://name/2/do_gas2/idi_centr=6354/mes=21
349  307 fs://name/2/do_des/mes=25
340  332 fs://name/1/venta/year=2018/month=12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {sub("/user/hive/ware",""); $4=($4~/1$/ ? 1 : 2)} 1' file
2557 386 fs://name/1/do_fact/date=20190313/fact=6
2593 393 fs://name/1/do_gas/idi_centr=6372/mes=20
2594 343 fs://name/2/do_gas2/idi_centr=6354/mes=21
349  307 fs://name/2/do_des/mes=25
340  332 fs://name/1/venta/year=2018/month=12
```

or if you don't REALLY want to remove the string `/user/hive/share` and instead want to remove the 4th through 6th fields no matter their value:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {$4=$5=$6="\n"; sub(/(\/\n){3}/,""); $4=($4~/1$/ ? 1 : 2)} 1' file
2557 386 fs://name/1/do_fact/date=20190313/fact=6
2593 393 fs://name/1/do_gas/idi_centr=6372/mes=20
2594 343 fs://name/2/do_gas2/idi_centr=6354/mes=21
349  307 fs://name/2/do_des/mes=25
340  332 fs://name/1/venta/year=2018/month=12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` and its `gsub` function to perform replacement on the selected columns.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{gsub("user/hive/ware/","");gsub(/^[^12]+/,"",$4)}1' inputfile
2557 386 fs://name/1/do_fact/date=20190313/fact=6
2593 393 fs://name/1/do_gas/idi_centr=6372/mes=20
2594 343 fs://name/2/do_gas2/idi_centr=6354/mes=21
349  307 fs://name/2/do_des/mes=25
340  332 fs://name/1/venta/year=2018/month=12
```

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's_/user/hive/ware/[^/]+(.)/_/\1/_' file

2557 386 fs://name/1/do_fact/date=20190313/fact=6
2593 393 fs://name/1/do_gas/idi_centr=6372/mes=20
2594 343 fs://name/2/do_gas2/idi_centr=6354/mes=21
349  307 fs://name/2/do_des/mes=25
340  332 fs://name/1/venta/year=2018/month=12
```

it's not really a conditional replacement.